# react native onPress and props

Tags: react-native, onpress

On react native, why can I call the return function to pass a prop, but when passing it in a composed function it won't work?

This works

```
           const pop = props.onPress;
...
         <TouchableOpacity style={styles.okButton} onPress={pop}>
```

But,

```
 function closee() {
  console.log('aaadsedf');
  props.onPress;
 }
...
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.okButton} onPress={closee}>
```

shows log working ok, but doesnt trigger the props.onPress

So how to properly call the onPress?
how to properly pass the composed function?

Comment: Try calling it like `props.onPress()`

Comment: done thanks! is the response, plz put as answer cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call it like:

```js
 function closee() {
  console.log('aaadsedf');
  props.onPress();
 }
```